# Math behind the perspective projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for some history and the actual development of the Math behind a perspective projection Matrix. I googled for it. I mostly find the final matrix everywhere, not exactly a derivation of it or the history behind it. Could anyone please provide some links/name of books where i can find a detailed account of this?

Thanks!
Mukund

Comment: [This page derives it](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/)

Answer (score 5):

I learned about the projection matrix during a course on mathematical modeling and I'm willing to share some basic concepts:

#### Concepts

```
Basic idea (*Coo stands for coordinates, Para for parameter)

        Camera Matrix      Persp Projection       Intrinsic Para Matrix
World Coo   <--->   Camera Coo   <--->   Image Plane Coo  <--->   Pixel Coo
     ↑                                                                ↑
     └━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┘
                             Projection Matrix
```

[Pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model) which is the easiest linear camera model we can conceive of.

[Transformation/Rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) means translation and rotation of objects based on our view.

[Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) has some explanation, and a link to [camera matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix).

#### Notations

[Homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics) which is rather useful. You may see that we can scale the homogenous coordinates without changing the point's coordinate in the projection plane.

#### Further Materials

[Fundamentals of Computer Vision](https://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558.html) page has slides and notes to computer vision and digital camera related topics. See slide/notes #1.

[Geometric Framework for Vision I: Single View and Two-View Geometry](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/EPSRC_SSAZ/epsrc_ssaz.html) by Andrew Zisserman has some fine material on projection matrices.

[3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development, 2ndE](http://gamemath.com/), a decent book on 3D gaming math basics. There are prepared slides and full code in C++.

Comment: There's a lot other concepts involved in my post (application of it) other than the Perspective Projection Matrix. The idea is the first three concepts in the diagram I drew in code block. The final step is necessary when it comes to rasterized receivers.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the book [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://books.google.de/books?id=si3R3Pfa98QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zisserman%20geometry&source=bl&ots=aQs0mvba7J&sig=BE7E_0b-AfU72MvjNbHaCzMG-80&hl=de&sa=X&ei=STAyUKzeI87EswbsgIEo&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=zisserman%20geometry&f=false) on that topic. It contains an accessible introduction to projection matrices and projective geometry which first treats the two-dimensional case and then moving on to the three dimensional case.